# How many hours since I unplugged my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, battery, charging

Mobile phones usually say this as "xyz hours on battery" by counting the time from when they are unplugged from power.

Can I find out how many hours has it been since I unplugged my Mac from charging adapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Mavericks take a look in the Activity Monitor's Energy sections bottom.

[image]